# ASP.net login control membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

Just 2 days ago I got to learn log-in controls and forms authentication in ASP .NET.

Before then I used to create my own database my user table and my own logic for log-in and log-out using sessions and sql server.

The new ways is cool as it allows me to do the work fast than before, but what when I use these log-in and create user control a default database ASPNETDB.MDF is saved in App_Data folder.

Since I use my single database for storing everything regarding my site, is it possible to store all the user information in my own database and in my own tables?

I want the power of new controls with the flexibility of my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to add a [SQL membership provider](http://odetocode.com/Articles/427.aspx) in your web.config and point it to the right DB, sample extracts below.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <clear/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MYDBNAME;User ID=foo;Password=bar" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>


    <membership>
        <providers>
            <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
            <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Also here a link on how to [Create the Membership Schema in SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own tables and not the ones that microsoft dictates you will need to use a custom membership provider [this article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm) will show you how you can do that.